# How to write filepath in ini's section with QSettings

Tags: c++, qt, filepath, ini, qsettings

I need to use filepath as a section name in ini file and I try to do it like this:

```
QSettings ini(iniPath, QSettings::IniFormat);
ini.beginGroup("C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\222.txt");
ini.setValue(attributeName, attributeValue);
...
ini.endGroup();
```

Then I try to read values from this section:

```
QSettings ini(iniPath, QSettings::IniFormat);
ini.beginGroup("C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\222.txt");
auto allKeys = ini.allKeys();
for (auto& key: allKeys)
{
   QString val = ini.value(key);
   ...
}
ini.endGroup();
```

But in the output file I can see just "[C%3AUsers%5CUsername%5CDocuments%5C222.txt]" as name of section. And most importantly that QSettings can't find this section when reads ini file, allKeys variable is always empty.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your code works very well on my computer. Yes, I get `C%3AUsers%5CUsername%5CDocuments%5C222.txt` too, but I can read all keys and read all settings, it is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. The code in my question is a little bit simplified. Code for writing and reading is located in methods "save" and "load". I Feel myself rather silly :( The problem was in the difference between input parameters in "save" and "load" methods. In "save" method input string was "C:\Users\Username\Documents\222.txt" and in "load" method it was "C:/Users/Username/Documents/222.txt" so when I tried to read the settings in "load" method QSettings didn't can find the section.

As I understand it QSettings escapes special characters like "\" with "%" symbol. And "/" symbol QSettings uses for making nestings. So I decide to use paths like "C:\Users\Username\Documents\222.txt" as is. It works fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [QSettings::Format](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#Format-enum) documentation:

> QSettings always treats backslash as a special character and provides no API for reading or writing such entries.

Comment: He can use "/" instead

Comment: @N1ghtLight I tried this, result was extremely bad `[C%3A]
Users\Username\Documents\222.txt\att=ex` Group was set incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use [QDir::fromNativeSeparators()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#fromNativeSeparators) for the section name. When you read back, just use the path as is (all Qt classes support it) or covert it to the Windows-style with [QDir::toNativeSeparators()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators).

Comment: QDir::fromNativeSeparators() just replace "//" on "\" and I get the same result like @Chernobyl